# Swap key,value inside a node.js collections dictionary

Tags: node.js, dictionary, collections, collectionsjs

I am using this node.js collection module. http://www.collectionsjs.com/

I would like to swap the key with the value inside a collections dictionary.

To illustrate, here is the original dictionary.

```
"use strict";
var Dict = require("collections/dict");

var Data_type = new Dict(
    {
        "00": "DATA_0",
        "01": "DATA_1",
        "02": "DATA_2",        
    });
```

After swapping, the new dictionary will look like this;

```
var Data_type_swapped = new Dict(
    {
        "DATA_0": "00",
        "DATA_1": "01",
        "DATA_2": "02",        
    });
```

There are no duplicate values in the original dictionary.

I am using node.js v6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the library, but I skimmed the documentation and came up with this:

```
let Dict = require('collections/dict');
let d = new Dict({ 'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2' });

d.keys().forEach(key => {
    d.set(d.get(key), key);
    d.delete(key); // This could cause trouble if your value is the same as your key
});
```

It iterates through all keys, adds a new entry identified by the value of the current key, sets its value and then deletes the old key